# No puedo ingresar un dato de una clave foránea Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia.

Realice un base de datos como proyecto para un hospital con MYSQL. Realice un formulario en HTML para agendar una cita de un paciente ya existente y ocupe PHP para realizar la inserción de los datos . Pero me manda el siguiente error.

BASE DE DATOS

```
TABLA pacienes (ID_PACIENTE int) PK
TABLA consulta (ID_CONSULTA int) PK
TABLA doctores (ID_DOCTOR int) PK
----
TABLA asignado (PACIENTE_ID)FK/(CONSULTA_ID)FK/(DOCTOR_ID)FK/
```

'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`base2`.`asignado`, CONSTRAINT `FK_DR` FOREIGN KEY (`DOCTOR_ID`) REFERENCES `doctores` (`ID_DOCTOR`) ON DELETE NO ACTION)'

PHP

```
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Conexion Fallida").mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    echo "Conexion Exitosa";
    echo "<br>";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO asignado (PACIENTE_ID, CONSULTA_ID, DOCTOR_ID, HORARIO) VALUES ('$_REQUEST[PACIENTE_ID]', '$_REQUEST[CONSULTA_ID]', '$_REQUEST[DOCTOR_ID]', '$_REQUEST[HORARIO]')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
              echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
              echo "!!UPS Algo salio mal!!: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Me podrían ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

buenas tardes.

Valida que las llaves que quieres insertar existen en su respectiva tabla. Para el error que te devuelve, revisa que el valor de la llave DOCTOR_ID exite en la tabla (doctores).

un saludo!

Comment: Bienvenido Wilfredo, te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por [answer] para poder mejorar tu respuesta... seria bueno que amplíes un poco mas la respuesta para el mejor entendimiento del OP...

Comment: Que tal Wilfredo. te comento. Actualmente tengo tres registros insertados en la tabla doctores. Si yo inserto un registro en la tabla asignado desde PHPMYADMIN no me marca ningún error . Pero a la hora de hacer el formulario con html y php si me marca ese error.